# How to find IMEI number using Ionic4 with angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I am new for Ionic framework. I need to identify every device uniquely. I think best way to obtain the IMEI number. But how can I do that? I have tried Ionic4 with Angular cordova using [this](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/uid/) documentation. Whenever I tried, it's showing cordova not available.

Comment: you have to try that on a physical device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMEI can be considered a privacy detail and some platforms might not allow obtaining that without user's consent etc.

Try using [Device Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/device) that should give you access to a uuid (unique device identifier) - uuid won't always be exactly the IMEI, but it should be unique based on a device.

See more docs here:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device

Caveats:

- for iOS/Android you need to run your app on real devices
- you should await for deviceready event before attemting to retrieve device data